# How to find all the Pending CLs in Perforce that contain a file in shelved mode?

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-client-spec

I have started using Perforce and have made a lot of pending changelists which have files shelved.

I was trying to find a specific change in a file.

Is it possible that i can narrow down my search to only those changelists that actually have the file in shelved mode ?

It would be great if i could give a substring too that would be searched automatically in file of those changelists or in all changelists. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [changes](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_changes.html) command, and specify the user, status, and file. Running `p4 changes -u <username> -s shelved //path/to/file` should return a list of all changelists from the specified user that have that file shelved.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of P4V, you can also do this visually if you want. In the pending changelist tab, you can check the box that says "Show only changes with shelved files", and change the Workspace filter dropdown, to the Files dropdown, and then filter on the file path you want to search for.

This will give you the benefit over the commandline of then being able to act on that shelve right there if you want.